# HTTPS request is not working in Node.js (Code 400)

Tags: node.js, rest, api, http-post, httprequest

I am new with Node.js and try to call an existing API with basic auth and header/body. [Here](https://github.com/zazaz-de/iot-device-bosch-indego-controller/blob/master/PROTOCOL.md) are more details about the API I try to use. I always receive a 400 code as response. Please check my attached code snippet:

```html
// Include the request library for Node.js   
var request = require('request');
//  Basic Authentication credentials   
var username = 'myEmail';
var password = 'mySuperSecret';
var authenticationHeader = "Basic " + new Buffer(username + ":" + password).toString("base64");

var json = '{"device":"","os_type":"Android","os_version":"4.0","dvc_manuf":"unknown","dvc_type":"unknown"}';
var jsonstring = JSON.stringify(json);

const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'https://api.indego.iot.bosch-si.com/api/v1/authenticate',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + new Buffer(username + ':' + password).toString('base64'),
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Content-Length': jsonstring.length
    },
    body : jsonstring
  }

  request(options, function(err, res, body) {  

  if (!err && res.statusCode == 200) {
    let jsonbody = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(jsonbody);
    console.log(res);
    console.log(res.statusCode);
  }
});
```

I also tried a web client to test the API and was successful: https://client.restlet.com/
[image]

Any suggestions what I did wrong?
Thanks,
tro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following and now it works:

```html
var request = require('request-promise');


var options = {
  method: 'POST',
  uri: 'https://api.indego.iot.bosch-si.com/api/v1/authenticate',
  
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Basic myBasicAuth',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Content-Length': '116'
  },
  
  body: {
      "device":"",
      "os_type":"Android",
      "os_version":"4.0",
      "dvc_manuf":"unknown",
      "dvc_type":"unknown"
  },
  json: true // Automatically stringifies the body to JSON
};



request(options, function (err, response, body) {
  var reason;
  if (err) {
      reason = {
          cause: err,
          error: err,
          options: options,
          response: response
      };
} else if (!(/^2/.test('' + response.statusCode))) { // Status Codes other than 2xx
      reason = {
          statusCode: response.statusCode,
          error: body,
          options: options,
          response: response
      };
  }
});
```

Comment: You have made my day...!! Thank you... @tro

Answer (score 0):

Couple of changes I would suggest you to make,

In your `options` variable the below line the `url` should be change to `uri` as,

```
uri: 'https://api.indego.iot.bosch-si.com/api/v1/authenticate',
```

Also place the display the response only when the call gets succeeds,

```
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    let jsonbody = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(jsonbody);
    console.log(res);
    console.log(res.statusCode);
  }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I changed what you suggested, but still not working :-( 400 code

Comment: Any other suggestions? Thx